# jquery-editable Select - Default value by current value selected

Tags: select, jquery-plugins

I use this code:

```js
$('.editable-select-works').editable('https://intra.kiwynet.com/works.asp', {
  id: 'pk',
  type: "select",
  loadurl: 'https://intra.kiwynet.com/works.asp?q_act=READWORKS',
  tooltip: 'Select the work',
  submit: "OK",
  style: "inherit",
  placeholder: 'Work',
  width: 125
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jeditable.js/2.0.7/jquery.jeditable.min.js"></script>
<span style="display: inline-block;width:250px;" id="572" class="editable-select-works" rrole="button" tabindex="0" title="Select the work">Builder</span><br>

<span style="display: inline-block;width:250px;" id="845" class="editable-select-works" rrole="button" tabindex="0" title="Select the work">Farmer</span><br>
```

it doesn't work snipped, but you can see it at this address https://intra.kiwynet.com/works.html

the problem is sending the current selected value to works.asp for example ?q_act=READWORKS&q_selected=BLD

for return

{"ART":"Artist","BLD":"Builder","FRM":"Farmer","selected":"BLD"}
Example:
https://intra.kiwynet.com/works.asp?q_act=READWORKS&q_selected=BLD

I would like to pass the id because so I can see what is written in the db. Or is there some other way?

I tested value: but without success,
i tried to insert a function in loadurl: but it is not supported apparently

any idea? Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

analyzing the function thoroughly I found that loadurl option also sends a series of parameters including the id, so for me it is enough

q_act=READWORKS&0=q&1=*&2=i&3=d&4=%3D&5=5&6=7&7=2&**pk=845**&*=1614789130874